# SQL select multiple records with limit on each iteration

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have array of timestamps `[1544539216000, 1544604587000]`; my target is to write a SQL query that for each timestamp return single record, which timestamp is less and closer to current timestamp. (Not sure how to cover cases like if there is no records between and second record return same rows as first..?) DB: Postgres. How is that possible.

**EDIT**

In other words - "Hey SQL take those timestamps and for each one of them return me a record which timestamp is less and closer". Output count must be equal to input count.

Code I have so far is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM public."myDate"
WHERE "createdAt" <= '1544539216000' AND "createdAt" <= '1544604587000'
ORDER BY id ASC
```

Comment: Sample data and expected result. A few rows will go a long way for us to understand your question.

Comment: @TheImpaler input: [1544539216000, 1544604587000], output => [{name: "Some Name", "createdAt:": "1544539216000"}, {name: "Some Name 2", "createdAt:": "1544604587000"}] from table with 100 records

Comment: do you mean union all and fetch first 1 record only?

Comment: No, I mean I input 10 timestamps and expect to get 10 records each one of them which is is less and closer to current timestamp

Comment: Sorry, I use 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will a plpsql solution do?

```
CREATE FUNCTION select_by_dates(double precision[])
RETURNS SETOF public."myDate"
AS $$
DECLARE
cur_ts double precision;
out record;
BEGIN
FOREACH cur_ts IN ARRAY $1
LOOP
Select * FROM public."myDate" WHERE "createdAt" < cur_ts ORDER  BY "createdAt" DESC LIMIT 1 INTO out;
RETURN NEXT out;
END LOOP;
RETURN;
END;

$$Language plpgsql;



select * from select_by_dates(ARRAY[1544539216000, 1544604587000]);
```

Comment: WHERE "createdAt" < cur_ts - operator does not exist: double precision < timestamp without time zone

Comment: Problem is that createdAt is stored as double precision. Besides that I like this approach. How can I fix it?

Comment: Just change the function definition to work with doubles instead of timestamps. I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Why do you use doubles instead of timestamps?

Comment: ERROR:  function "select_by_dates" already exists with same argument types
SQL state: 42723

Comment: How can I define function only once?

Comment: `DROP function select_by_dates(timestamp[])`

Comment: So I should declare it and drop it on every request? Last thing how can I return first record if ts is smaller than it?

Comment: Last thing how can I return first record if ts is smaller than it?

Comment: Read the docs on [plpgsql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW) you can use `SELECT * INTO` like above with  `IF NOT FOUND THEN`